# How to find neighbour order by another colum mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is,

I have a table in mysql

which colums are

```
  id   Student   score  
  1     A         55 
  2     B         86
  3     C         65
  4     D         23
  5     E         84
  6     F         45
  7     G         80
```

I want to find rank of any student in whole class based on score, with the student who scored just greater them him and an another student who scored just less them him.
for example if I am searching for student E

then output should be

```
   id   User   score  rank_in_classs
    2    B      86         1
    5    E      84         2
    7    G      80         3
```

An another example can be that if I am looking for student A

```
   id   User   score  rank_in_classs
    3    c      65         4
    1    A      55         5
    6    F      45         6
```

How can I find it using mysql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### **Query**

```
SELECT id, Student, score, 
FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM tbl )
) AS rank_in_class
FROM tbl
ORDER BY rank_in_class
LIMIT 3;
```

### [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e9e/20)

Comment: Thanks , but let I want to find records based on "Student A", How can I do it ? please see second example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the FIND_IN_SET() based solution proposed by Ullas you can locate a particular student +/- 1 rank this way:

```
set @this_rank := (
                    SELECT
                          FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
                                                SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
                                                ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                                                FROM tbl 
                                                )
                                     ) AS rank_in_class
                    FROM tbl
                    where student = 'A'
                    );
select
*
from (
      SELECT
            id
          , Student
          , score
          , FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
                                  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
                                  ORDER BY score DESC ) 
                                  FROM tbl 
                                  )
                       ) AS rank_in_class
      FROM tbl
     ) ric
where rank_in_class between @this_rank-1 AND @this_rank+1
ORDER BY rank_in_class
LIMIT 3;
```

Note: **IF** you stored the rank value in the table, then this would not be so cumbersome and could perform way better.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is probably with a mix of two queries and a little of PHP.

- The first query retrieves the rank of the "focused" student you want;
- The second query retrieves the range of all the students around the focused "student" with a dynamic `LIMIT` statement (this is where the use of PHP is unavoidable);

So something like this would probably do the job :

```
$user = 'C'; // Student user we want to "focus"
$range = 1; // Range around the "focus" : 1 before and 1 after (could be changed to anything else)

// First query : retrieving the rank of the "focused" student
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS Rank FROM Student AS Focused INNER JOIN Student as Others ON Others.Score > Focused.Score OR (Others.Score = Focused.Score AND Others.Id > Focused.Id) WHERE Focused.user = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$user);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
$startRank = $res['Rank'];

// Computing the dynamic LIMIT
if (($startRank - $range) < 1) {
  $offset = 0;
  $rowCount = $startRank + $range + 1;
} else {
  $offset = $startRank - $range;
  $rowCount = ($range * 2)+1;
}

// Second query : retrieving the rank of all the students around the "focused" student
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, user, score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM Student, (SELECT @curRank := ?) Rank ORDER BY Score DESC, id DESC LIMIT ?, ?');
$stmt->bind_param('iii',$offset,$offset,$rowCount);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is probably the most optimized way to query the database to get what you want.  As a bonus, you can change the range to whatever you like.